# Creating a Monthly Schedule with Random Work Hours for Employees in Neo4j

Tags: database, database-design, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to get all the workers who stayed overtime.
So, I'm  trying to create a schedule in Neo4j using Cypher, where each month has several weeks and each week has seven days with fixed work hours. Each worker has their own schedule that depicts the actual time they come to and leave work. I've got a few `employee` nodes populated with sample data like this:

```
CREATE (:Employee {employee_id: randomUUID(), name: 'John Doe', sex: 'Male', salary: 25000000, age: 35, job_title: 'Manager', date_of_joining: '2018-01-01', email_address: 'johndoe@example.com', department: 'Sales'})
CREATE (:Employee {employee_id: randomUUID(), name: 'Jane Smith', sex: 'Female', salary: 20000000, age: 28, job_title: 'Marketing Manager', date_of_joining: '2019-05-01', email_address: '[janesmith@example.com](mailto:janesmith@example.com)', department: 'Marketing'})
```

and so on. Now I want to run a query for employees who worked on a certain day of the week and stayed overtime:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[:HAS_SCHEDULE]->(s:Schedule)-[:HAS_SHIFT]->(w:WorkShift)
WHERE s.monday_start <= w.start AND s.monday_end >= w.end AND w.end > '15:00'
RETURN e.name, s.monday_start, s.monday_end, w.start, w.end
```

So each employee that I want to target has their workshift time (the time they're supposed to be at work) and their actual schedule time.

I tried to create a `Schedule` node with 12 `Month` nodes, each containing several `Week` nodes, and each `Week` node containing 7 `Day` nodes with their respective start and end times:

```
 // Create Month nodes
FOREACH (idx in RANGE(0, 11) |
  CREATE (:Month {value: date({year: 2023, month: idx+1, day: 1}).toString()})
)

// Create Week nodes for each Month
MATCH (m:Month)
WITH m, range(1, date({year: 2023, month: m.value.split("-")[1], day: 1}).weeks) as weeks
UNWIND weeks as week
CREATE (:Week {value: week})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(m)

// Create Day nodes for each Week
MATCH (w:Week)
WITH w, range(0, 6) as days
UNWIND days as day
CREATE (:Day {value: day})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(w)

// Create Schedule nodes for each Employee
MATCH (e:Employee)
WITH e, range(0, 11) as months
UNWIND months as month
MERGE (e)-[:HAS_SCHEDULE]->(:Schedule)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(m:Month {value: date({year: 2023, month: month+1, day: 1}).toString()})
WITH e, m
MATCH (s:Schedule)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(m)
WITH s, range(1, date({year: 2023, month: m.value.split("-")[1], day: 1}).weeks) as weeks
UNWIND weeks as week
MATCH (w:Week)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(m)
WHERE w.value = week
WITH s, w, range(0, 6) as days
UNWIND days as day
WITH s, w, day, rand() as random
WITH s, w, day, random * 8 + 9 as start, random * 4 + 13 as end
CREATE (:ScheduleDay {value: day, start_time: toString(start) + ":00", end_time: toString(end) + ":00"})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(s)-[:HAS_DAY]->(:Day {value: day})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(w)
```

But it won't work; it says:

> `"}" (line 3, column 75 (offset: 130))"  CREATE (:Month {value: date({year: 2023, month: idx+1, day: 1}).toString()})"`

I guess each worker should be assigned a shift:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)-[:HAS_SCHEDULE]->(s:Schedule),
      (e)-[:HAS_SHIFT]->(ws:WorkShift)
WHERE s.monday_start <= ws.start AND s.monday_end >= ws.end
MERGE (e)-[:ON_SHIFT {day: 'Monday'}]->(ws)
RETURN e.name, ws.start, ws.end
```

In summary, I'm trying to create a schedule in Neo4j using Cypher for employees who work on a certain day of the week. I've created `Employee` nodes with sample data and a schedule consisting of 12 Month nodes, each containing several Week nodes, and each Week node containing 7 Day nodes with their respective start and end times.

However, I'm encountering issues when trying to create Schedule nodes for each employee, including a schedule that depicts the actual time workers come and leave and WorkShifts that consist of three parts and each worker is assigned a shift.

My initial approach could be completely derailed.

How do I refine my query to include the additional schedule and workshift details?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: That error looks like a syntax error (and the error message seems to be incomplete; what else does the error state?)

Comment: The error you cited is caused by the fact that a `date` has no `toString()` method. You need to replace `date({year: 2023, month: idx+1, day: 1}).toString()` with `TOSTRING(date({year: 2023, month: idx+1, day: 1})`. But that is just the first of many errors (some of which are of similar nature to the above). At this point you have too many syntactic issues with your code to even discuss how to tackle your use case. You should spend more time debugging the issues on your own and then, if necessary, write separate questions about each remaining issue.